# Adding rows in Two dimensional arrays

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to make the 2048 game using two dimensional arrays. I need some with help with a question.
basically im trying to figure out to combine the numbers, while that sound very vague I think an example would be better.
if I wanted to add upwards:

[2][4][8][16]

^   ^  ^   ^

|   |   |   |

[2][4][8][16].

basically how do I add rows in multi-dimensional arrays.
I've thought of using simple inefficient if statements but the logic would take forever to write.
I'm thinking there's a more simple way of adding row 2 to row 1.
Btw, I'm having the computer make it's own moves with a randomizer based system. It basically pics a number between 1-4 and if the number is equal to 1 it goes upwards.
Also I'm having the numbers in exponents with a base of 2. Here's my code so far(pls forgive the indenting):

```
int main()
{
    class GameConfig{

        public : int Size[4][4] = {};
        void Rpos(int x, int y){
            //begins with a random position*//
         x = rand() % 15;
         y = rand() % 15;
        if (x == y)
            {
            x - 1;
        }

        Size[x][y];
    }
        void Play(){
            int trns = 1;
            while(trns == 1)
            {
            int Dir = rand() %  4 + 1;
            }
            if()

        }
}game;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Arrays cannot be resized.  Once you declare a 2D array, you're stuck with that size.  Use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, where you actually can add (or remove) rows dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Adding rows are very easy in two dimensional arrays e.g

I'm assuming your 2048 game is of 4*4 matrix

```
void addRows(int matrix[4][4],int row1,int row2,int col)
{
  for(int i= 0;i<col;i++)
  {

     matrix[row1][i]+=matrix[row2][i];
  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes it is. thank you so much for your help! I appreciate it.